# How to apply tool tip arrow triangle shadow

Tags: html, css

I need to create tooltip with a box and shadow around it, however, I'm having difficulty to apply it, the  box shadow doesn't apply well around the comment box.

I already check in different answer and tried to apply it, however, the shape that I want to make it work doesn't work, I attached an image for the shape that I'm looking to apply with the shadow, will be really appreciate if anyone can solve the issue.

```css
.test-shadow{
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 40%;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;




    position: relative;
    margin: 3em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.test-shadow:before {
    content: "";
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
position: absolute;
/*border-top: 20px solid transparent;*/
/*border-right: 15px solid #f7f7f8;*/
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
/*box-shadow: 0 2px 25px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);*/
/*background-color: #FFFFFF;*/

border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid #06386c;


box-sizing: border-box;
transform: rotate(-180deg);
border: 1em solid black;
border-color: transparent transparent #FFFFFF #FFFFFF;

transform-origin: 0 0;

box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="test-shadow">Lorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si ametLorem ipsum dolor si amet</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking it down into two elements (the arrow and the text box) with a wrapper around them so you can position the whole thing more easily. Then play around with the positions of the shadow until it looks good and you do not get a weird overlap.

In my example I used an SVG to create the arrow. And I gave it a `z-index` of `999` and the text box a `z-index` of `-999` so the arrow will be on top of the text box and you will only have to play around with the position of its shadow, trying to match the text box shadow and making sure it doesn't overlap the text box on the right side.

```css
body {
    background: FloralWhite;
}

.text-container {
    margin: 3em;
}

.test-shadow {
    float: left;
    z-index: -999;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 80%;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: white;
}

.svg-arrow {
    float: left;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -7px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07));
            filter: drop-shadow( -7px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07));
}

.svg-arrow polygon{
    fill: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-arrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <polygon points="0,0 20,0 20,20"></polygon>
    </svg>
    <div class="test-shadow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eget tristique felis, vitae pretium sem.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad this answer was useful for you.